# Can cert manager+letsencrypt issue certificates to hosts matching default k8s backend?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

```
spec:
    defaultBackend:
      service:
        name: svc-1
        port:
          number: 80
    rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: svc-1
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    - host: example2.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: svc-2
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific

ingress:
 - ip: w.x.y.z
```

As far as I understand cert-manager can issue certificates for example.com and example2.com since the hosts are defined in the ingress config. Is it possible to get the certificate issued to example3.com (say example3.com is pointed to ip w.x.y.z in DNS) without having to manually create a certificate request?

Comment: not sure that is possible, will check

Comment: after a while time and tries(sorry for delay) I can tell you (unfortunately)  that you do need manually create request. I know this comment doesnt help you, so please, post your own  answer in case you find a way during last 1,5 month

Answer (score -1):

For HTTP-01 verification cert-manager creates its own ingress resource so it shouldn't matter if you have any other ingress in your cluster for the same DNS name. Just create the certificate request resource as usual.

For DNS validation the ingresses are absolutely irrelevant, so you can absolutely get your certificate if you use that.